# How to render conditional navbar links based on the route you are on?

Tags: reactjs

My react site basically consists of two routes. The homepage and then a contact page. I am using react-router-dom to switch between the two routes. If I am on the Contact page how do I get the navbar to display "Close" instead of Contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard providing an answer without knowing your code structure.

`react-router-dom` offers multiple options that can benefit your goal. I'd suggest you first look into the [`match`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/match) object and [`useRouteMatch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook or the [`location`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) attribute in the route props and [`useLocation`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook.

Comment: yes, I think useLocation will work perfectly. I just needed to know how to get the value of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the navbar is a component of its own (if its not then just change the values), you could pass in a prop with different values from each of your pages, e.g a prop called currentPage and you could pass in "home" from the home route and "contact" from the contact route, and use the ternary operator in the navbar to decide which one to display. Something like `props.currentPage == "home ? "Contact" : "Close"`. Hope this helps in some way.